# Как найти граничные воксели (пиксели) по бинарной маске?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть воксельное множество размера 512х512хN (N - количество срезов томографии) (`new BitArray(512х512хN)`).

В результате одного из алгоритмов сегментации получаются индексы закрашенных вокселей в этом множестве, для обозначения необходимых вокселей используется массив BitArray, где индексы со значением true - сегмент, а false - фон.

Как найти граничные воксели (пиксели) по бинарной маске, в которой хранятся их координаты (x,y,z) и информация фон это или нет (true - false)), для получения только оболочки сегмента?

Вот код определения граничных индексов, но он не верен:

```
private static async Task<BitArray> EdgeArray(Vector3Int size, BitArray data)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var edges = new BitArray(data.Length);
            var mask3d = new Dictionary<Vector3Int,bool>();

            Parallel.For(0, data.Count, i =>
            {
                lock (mask3d)
                {
                    mask3d.Add(size.GetIndex3D(i),data[i]);
                }
            });

            var voxels = mask3d.Keys.ToList();

            Parallel.For(0, voxels.Count, i =>
            {
                if (voxels[i].x == 0 || voxels[i].x == size.x - 1 || voxels[i].y == 0 ||
                    voxels[i].y == size.y - 1 || voxels[i].z == 0 || voxels[i].z == size.z - 1)
                {
                    if (mask3d[voxels[i]])
                    {
                        var index = voxels[i].ToIndex3D(size.x, size.y, size.z);
                        edges[index] = true;
                        Debug.Log(index);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mask3d[voxels[i]] && (!mask3d[voxels[i-1]] || !mask3d[voxels[i+1]]))
                    {
                        var index = voxels[i].ToIndex3D(size.x, size.y, size.z);
                        edges[index] = true;
                        Debug.Log(index);
                    }
                }
            });
            return edges;
        });
    }
```

Вспомогательные функции:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// returns the index in the 3d representation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector3Int"> array size in 3d representation </param>
    /// <param name="index"> 1d index </param>
    /// <returns>index in the 3d representation</returns>
    public static Vector3Int GetIndex3D(this Vector3Int vector3Int, int index)
    {
        return new Vector3Int
        {
            z = index / (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y),
            y = index % (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y) / vector3Int.x,
            x = index % (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y) % vector3Int.x
        };
    }
    
    public static int ToIndex3D(this Vector3Int vector3Int, int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        return vector3Int.z * width * height + vector3Int.y * width + vector3Int.x*depth;
    }
```

Помогите, кто чем может, пожалуйста

Comment: подсказка: `Parallel.For...lock (mask3d)` - эта конструкция отработает значительно медленнее и затратнее по ресурсам, чем обычный цикло `for`.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Смысл там в том, что вы тратите ресурсы на параллельность, но одновременно сможет отработать только один поток из всей пачки, так как все тело параллельного цикла защищено одним и тем же локом. Как итог, получится медленнее, чем стандартный `for`.

Comment: подсказка #2: `private static async ... return await`, когда кроме одного `return await` в асинхронном методе ничего нет, можно сделать его синхронным и просто внутренний `Task` пробросить в возвращаемое значение. Другими словами в методе `EdgeArray` можно выкинуть `async` и `await`, и ничего не поменяется, но скомпилированный код будет значительно проще и легче, и будет немного быстрее работать. (к сожалению, по алгоритму не могу ничего подсказать, не шарю)